# MongoDB equivalent to EF Core discriminator

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm currently switching my project to mongodb and I'd like to know if it's possible to do such things using the mongodb C# driver:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>()
        .HasDiscriminator<int>("ContractType")
        .HasValue<MobileContract>(1)
        .HasValue<BroadbandContract>(2);
```

I have tried something like creating a `BSonSerializer` and then registering the classes in the `BsonClassMap`, but I'm wondering if this is the best approach.

```cs
public class ContractDeserializer : IBsonSerializer<Contract>
{
    public Type ValueType => typeof(Contract);

    public Contract Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        context.Reader.ReadStartDocument();
        var contractType = context.Reader.FindElement("ContractType").Value.AsInt32;
        Contract contract;

        switch (contractType)
        {
            case 1:
                contract = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<MobileContract>(context.Reader);
                break;

            case 2:
                contract = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BroadbandContract>(context.Reader);
                break;

            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException($"ContractType {contractType} is not supported.");
        }

        context.Reader.ReadEndDocument();
        return contract;
    }

    public void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, Contract value)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Contract is an abstract class and should not be serialized directly.");
    }
}
```

```cs
public static void RegisterClassMaps()
{
    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Contract>(cm =>
    {
        cm.AutoMap();
        cm.SetIsRootClass(true);
        cm.SetDiscriminatorIsRequired(true);
        cm.SetSerializer(new ContractDeserializer());
    });

    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MobileContract>(cm => cm.AutoMap());
    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<BroadbandContract>(cm => cm.AutoMap());
}
```